# Group sublayers in WMS service to a single layer

Tags: qgis, wms

I created a WMS service in QGIS that consists of several sub layers. It is a base map of cadastral data that is stored in different tables to get the final look. In the QGIS project for the WMS I grouped the sublayers.

If I add the WMS to another QGIS project, I can still see all sublayers. Is there a way to make only the group layer visible / exposed via WMS?

[image]

Comment: Possibly, this could be done with MapProxy, Merging WMS: https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/configuration_examples.html